# Special Puzzling

Tags: pattern

[image]

How to solve this puzzling?
I can't see any links between them.

This is from AEGT-P test.

Comment: (Sorry about the "off-topic" bit of the message above. We have only limited ability to customize those messages. Obviously this isn't at all _off topic_, but we do require attribution for puzzles found elsewhere -- and original puzzles are generally better received. Thanks!)

Comment: Can you clarify what the "AEGT-P test" is? Is it a thing you can give a link to, for instance? (I'm guessing not; Google doesn't seem to have heard of it.)

Comment: I wonder if it might be [this](https://targetstudy.com/exams/aget/)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer with visuals (Blue is the X)

> [image]

Because the figure is

> 3d

Example:

> [image]

With each pair of images

> The camera rotates around 180 degrees

So the pattern is

> Top, bottom, left, right(upside down), front, **back (upside down)**

So it would look like:

> **White, black, white on top... long tail down to the x orb**

Comment: +1 for 3d image observation

Comment: I defer my answer to this. Yay for smart people.

Answer (score 5):

This would be my guess:

> [image]

because

> Each image is a mirror across the horizontal axis (top to bottom) of the one before it. But I would also guess that when the flip happens, the circle with the "X" changes to an empty circle if it is touching a black circle. This feels too simple to be right, but it's all I've got right now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my theory:

> It looks like the structure in each pair is flipped horizontally. After that, they two patterns (the x and solid) drop down vertically. So the last pattern should be the previous one flipped 180 degrees.